# Populating shortcode values dynamically in theme template

Tags: jquery, shortcode

I'm trying to use a jquery toggle shortcode in a theme template.

The shortcode goes like this:

```
[sws_toggle3 title="Title"]You can now see the displayed text.[/sws_toggle3]
```

I want to pull posts from a specific category and use the toggle to display them in the page.

This is what my theme template currently has:

```
    <?php
        $wp_query->query('cat=11&paged='  . $paged);
        while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();?>
        <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <h2><a class="title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <div class="post">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

With the output being something like:

```
[sws_toggle3 title="<?php the_title(); ?>"]<?php the_content(); ?>[/sws_toggle3]
```

Is this possible? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `do_shortcode()`, with a few modifications:

```
<?php
echo do_shortcode( '[sws_toggle3 title="' . get_the_title() . '"]' . get_the_content() . '[/sws_toggle3]' );
?>
```

**EDIT**

If you need to maintain the formatting of `the_content()`, simply pass `get_the_content()` through the appropriate filter:

```
<?php
$content = get_the_content();
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
echo do_shortcode( '[sws_toggle3 title="' . get_the_title() . '"]' . $content . '[/sws_toggle3]' );
?>
```

Comment: ah, beat me to it!

Comment: More like, we both posted at exactly the same time!

Comment: This worked, but lost the formatting as well.

Comment: See update for how to maintain formatting.

Comment: I tried the update and still doesn't hold the formatting. Tried modifying, but still no dice.



<?php
$wp_query->query('cat=11&paged='  . $paged);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) :
$wp_query->the_post();
$content = get_the_content();
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
echo do_shortcode( '[sws_toggle3 title="' . get_the_title() . '"]' . $content . '[/sws_toggle3]' );?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>

this is what i have right now

Answer (score 1):

use [`do_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode):

```
$wp_query->query('cat=11&paged='  . $paged);

while ($wp_query->have_posts()) :

    $wp_query->the_post();
    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content',get_the_content() );
    $title = the_title('','',false);
    $shortcode = '[sws_toggle3 title="'.$title.'"]'.$content.'[/sws_toggle3]';
    echo do_shortcode($shortcode);

endwhile;
```

Comment: Thanks! I both of them worked to get the toggle to pull the content, the title and content lost all its formatting.